# How many people can be on a Google Hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

The documentation says ten people can be in a Hangout but I'm hearing that Hangout video maxes out at six people.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 10):

You can use Hangouts to talk with more than one person at the same time.

- Conversations can include up to 150 people.
- Video calls can include up to 10 ([Gmail](https://www.google.com/gmail/about/), [G Suite Basic](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6043385)) or 25 ([Business, Education](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6043385)) people.

Everyone who wants to join a group conversation must use Hangouts.

[Source](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3111943).

---

<del>For the desktop environment:</del>

> <del>**Specifications for sending and receiving messages**</del>
>
> <del>You can have a group Hangout with up to 100 people</del>.

---

> <del>**Requirements and specifications for video calls**</del>
>
> <del>Video calls can have a maximum of 10 participants</del>.

<del>[Source](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1216376?hl=en)</del>.

<del>In general:</del>

> <del>Sometimes you want to have a Hangout with multiple people at once, like when you're planning a trip with several friends or choosing a convenient meeting time. With Hangouts, you can have a discussion with up to 100 people and have a video call with up to 10 people</del>.

<del>[Source](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3111943)</del>.

<del>Also:</del>

> <del>Hangouts video calls are limited to 10 video conference participants, with no time limit. You can also use Hangouts On Air to broadcast a Hangout to many more people, though there is still a limit of 10 active participants</del>.
>
> <del>If you [activate Google+ premium features](https://support.google.com/a/answer/answer.py?answer=2701307), the limit increases to 15 participants for both Hangouts video calls and Hangouts On Air. The limit remains at 10, however, for Hangouts created from the Google+ Events page</del>.

<del>[Source](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1261833?hl=en)</del>.

Comment: The quotes are obsolete. For the current limits checkout the cited sources.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

While video Hangouts for personal users is [limited to 10 users](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/), the current limit is [15 simultaneous users](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/products/hangouts/) in Google Hangouts for Business Apps.

Answer (score 2):

The new video calls limit for Google Apps for Work (Work, Gov and Edu) is now 25.
"Hold video calls with up to 25 participants."

See the following article under "Google Apps editions"
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6065029?hl=en

Google announced this new limit on 3/16/2016 via the blog:
http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2016/03/connect-with-more-people-using-google.html

Answer (score 1):

You can now have 150 people in a standard text hangout, and video calls can have 25 participants.

Comment: No cited source

Answer (score 1):

The limits posted by Alex above apply to Google Hangouts using a free Gmail account.

For paying G Suite customers, there is another product for video-conferencing called Hangouts Meet which can support between 100 and 250 participants, depending on the pricing plan. [Source.](https://gsuite.google.com/compare-editions/?feature=meet)

Update: Until July 1, 2020 Google has upgraded the limits for Hangouts Meet to match the Enterprise-level plan (250 participants, live-streaming with up to 100.000 watchers) for all G Suite and G Suite for Education customers. [Source](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/helping-businesses-and-schools-stay-connected-in-response-to-coronavirus).

Answer (score 0):

Now 2016, Google Hangout support maximum 25 concurrent users (enterprise/education version). If you use Hangout on Air, everybody can watch with no limit.

Comment: No cited source

Answer (score -1):

It seems that Hangouts supports up to 10 people call on a free account:

> You can add up to 9  people in a Hangouts video call ([Source](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3110347?hl=en))